# Dealing with division errors in PostgresQL without procedural code - is it possible?

Tags: postgresql, exception, stored-procedures

I have to produce (in PostgresQL, if that matters) a table containing a column with the quotient of two sums, basically like this (quite simplified):

```
select name, sum(a)/sum(b), sum(c)/sum(d)
from a_complex_nested_select_query_with_many_zeros
group by name
order by name;
```

The table has tens of thousands of rows (not too big), but in a few cases, summing over b or d does produce 0, which causes the whole query to fail with `Divide by 0`.

In researching how to deal with the exception, I was only able to find information on [PL/pgSQL Control Structures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html), which appears to require the creation of a function (but I'm not sure).

My question is of course how to make this query work. Perhaps the answer has something to do with

- Can an exception be caught in non-procedural SQL (PostgresQL, perhaps?)
- Is this a case where procedural code is necessary?
- Can a CASE..WHEN..ELSE..END structure avoid the problem (I'm stuck on this because it looks like the SUM() calls are repeated!), but it is appealing because I do not know enough about Postgres to know whether exception catching has a performance penalty.
- Is there a way to, again without a function, ensure SUM() is evaluated once in a CASE expression?
- If a function is required, what would it look like?

**EDIT** By "repeating sum calls" I mean that I know I *could* write:

```
select name, 
    case when sum(b)=0 then null else sum(a)/sum(b) end,
    case when sum(d)=0 then null else sum(c)/sum(d) end
```

and so on, but am not sure if that is a good thing. (I guess someone will answer with a why-don't-you-profile-it but I think there may be better approaches out there, somewhere.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't resist: why don't you run an `explain analyze` and see for yourself? Exception handling in PL/pgSQL is quite expensive, so I would first test the `case` solution. If you want to make *sure* it's only evaluated once, use a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nullif`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) will return null if the arguments are equal. A division by `null` evaluates to `null`

```
select
    name,
    sum(a) / nullif(sum(b), 0),
    sum(c) / nullif(sum(d), 0)
from a_complex_nested_select_query_with_many_zeros
group by name
order by name;
```

Comment: That's very nice. Who would have known my the name that the result would be null if they were equal? Works perfectly.